# Is it Possible to Migrate a Database from SQL Server to PostGresQL using Nhibernate?

Tags: sql, nhibernate

Basically, I just want to know if its possible to use Nhibernate to migrate between databases?

Comment: dup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365067/if-i-use-nhibernate-can-i-switch-between-databases-and-not-change-the-nhibernate

Comment: not sure about moving data, but the schema could be easily migrated using FluenNhibernate http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Schema_generation

Comment: @Remus--These two questions are different. This one is about migration and the other is about Nhibernate code between databases.

Comment: @luke101, by "migrate" you mean the database structure or structure + Data ?

Comment: Yes strucure and data. Can this be done by nhibernate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you must use some other tool to do the migration, and then you can continue to use nHibernate (the level of compatibility will depend on your code)

Tools:

- [Full Convert](http://www.spectralcore.com/fullconvert/adwlanding5-search.php?source=sql2pg&kw=Sql%20server%20to%20postgresql&adsrc=google-cpc-search&gclid=COmE1OCR1pwCFRhinAod6Fs4Jg)
- [MS2PG](http://edoceo.com/creo/ms2pg)